# Unlock using DevicePolicyManager

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

My application will set as active admin using `DevicePolicyManager` . I am setting a password like '1234' using `DevicePolicyManager.resetPassword()` method. Is it possible to unlock the phone without asking the default lock screen (I want pass the already used password "1234" as keylock input).

Code I have used to lock:

```
mDPM.resetPassword("1234", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

Answer (score -1):

I doubt, we can't unlock password protected phone programmatically. [Check this if phone is not password protected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html).